# Webhost ads say they will "Promote your site to search engines". What do they really do?

Tags: seo, web-hosting

In several webhost commercials, ads, and benefits charts theres sometimes a feature where they will promote or advertise your site to search engines. Usually its part of the package but sometimes they charge money. But what do they actually do?

Only thing I can think of is these sites have link farm sites, which IIRC might *hurt* your ranking.

What do they usually do? For future reference, are these features worth it?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say and you really should ask them or see if their site offers any details about that service. But the odds are it just means they submit your site to the search engines or offers XML sitemaps tools or submissions. Maybe even free Adwords vouchers or something along those lines. I'm sure it's nothing that costs them money or helps you much at all.

Comment: In my experience it's usually one of those tools that submits your site to every minor search engine that gets 1 hit a day.